# ROS2 Controller does not configure correctly

Tags: ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I'm trying to set up a Velocity Controller for my Drone Propellers. When i start the controller.launch the JointStateBroadcaster configures correctly while the Rotor_controller fails. Terminal says that no joint parameter is set for the rotor_Controller. I only declared one propeller to keep it a little bit cleaner.

Terminal Error:

```
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710420076.765483836] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710420076.823491066] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'rotor_controller'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710420076.920064182] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710420076.920309607] [simple_drone.joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1710420077.022820726] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'rotor_controller'
[gzserver-4] [ERROR] [1710420077.022942884] [simple_drone.rotor_controller]: 'joints' parameter was empty
[gzserver-4] [WARN] [1710420077.022996415] [simple_drone.rotor_controller]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[gzserver-4] [ERROR] [1710420077.023028316] [simple_drone.controller_manager]: After configuring, controller 'rotor_controller' is in state 'unconfigured' , expected inactive.
```

My rotor_controller.yaml-File:

```
simple_drone/controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10
    use_sim_time: true

    rotor_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
        - rotation1
      
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
```

My Launch-File for controller

```
def generate_launch_description():

    robot_description = ParameterValue(
        Command(
        [
            "xacro ",
            os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("drone_description"), "urdf", "drone.urdf.xacro")
        ]
        ),
        value_type=str
    )

    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "simple_drone/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    rotor_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "rotor_controller",
            "--controller-manager",
            "simple_drone/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        robot_state_publisher,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        rotor_controller_spawner
    ])
```

My URDF Part for the Controller:

````
  <xacro:macro name="rotor1_transmission">
    <transmission name="rotation1_tran">
        <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
        <actuator name="rotation1_motor" role="actuator1"/>
        <joint name="rotation1" role="joint1">
            <mechanical_reduction>1.0</mechanical_reduction>
        </joint>
    </transmission>
</xacro:macro>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
      <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
      <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
      <parameters>$(find drone_bringup)/config/rotor_controller.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

<ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <joint name="rotation1">
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>

    </ros2_control>

```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your parameter yaml: You set the joints inside the controller_manager namespace, but it is a different node and not a parameter of the controller manager:

```
simple_drone/controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10
    use_sim_time: true

    rotor_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
      
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

simple_drone/rotor_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - rotation1
```

As I suggested in the other question: Use ros2cli to introspect the nodes, namespaces, and parameters. Also rqt, especially rqt_dynamic_reconfigure is your friend here.